# Unable to display list item

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I am creating a simple single page food recipes application. I am trying to display a list of recipes which the user can select from but for some reason, it won;t read the property of the recipe object within the recipe array. An error message keeps appearing when recompiling which says "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Recipe[]'".

Here is the recipes.html file:

```
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <h2>Recipes</h2>
<div *ngFor="let recipeEl of recipe">
    <a 
    href="#"
    class="list-group-item clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipeEl.name }}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipeEl.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <img 
        [src]="recipeEl.imagePath" 
        alt="{{ recipeEl.name }}"
        class="img-responsive"
        style="max-height: 50px">
    </span>
</a>
</div>
```

Here is the recipes.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from './recipes.model';
import { Recipeservice } from './recipes.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.component.css'],
})
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() recipe: Recipe[];

  constructor(private recipeService: Recipeservice) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipe = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
  }

}
```

Here is the recipes.model.ts file:

import { Ingredient } from "../shared/ingredient.model";

```
export class Recipe { 
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public imagePath: string;
  public ingredients: Ingredient[];

  constructor(name: string, desc: string, imagePath: string, ingredients: Ingredient[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
  }
}
```

Here is the recipes.service.ts file:

```
import { Recipe } from './recipes.model';
import { Ingredient } from '../shared/ingredient.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Recipeservice {

    private recipes: Recipe[] = [
        new Recipe('Spaghetti Carbonara', 'Authentic Italian Carbonara', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/08/13/13/pasta-712664_960_720.jpg', [
            new Ingredient('Spaghetti', 500),
            new Ingredient('Lardons', 20),
            new Ingredient('egg', 4),
            new Ingredient('parmesan', 100),
            new Ingredient('Garlic', 1),
            new Ingredient('Olive Oil', 50)
        ])
    ]

        getRecipes() {
            return this.recipes.slice();
        }

}
```

Comment: Please don't use the [angularjs] tag for [angular] questions

Comment: I assume you're doing something like `*ngFor="let recipe..." somewhere? Can you post that

Comment: Recipe is an array you have to iterate it

Comment: You dont iterate your array. Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to show us your code?

Comment: Recipe[] is an array (of objects) so it you need to loop through the array with ngFor as suggested above. Something like this (where the name of the array is recipes (plural)) <div class="pull-left" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
    </div>

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. Apologies for using the wrong tag, I will remember this for future posts. Tzimpo answered my question below many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe iterate your array with ***ngFor="let recipe of recipes**" like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
   <a href="#"class="list-group-item clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
       <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
    </div>
   <span class="pull-right">
    <img 
    [src]="recipe.imagePath" 
    alt="{{ recipe.name }}"
    class="img-responsive"
    style="max-height: 50px">
   </span>
   </a>
</div
```

Comment: *And rename `recipe` in component to `recipes`.

Comment: *And wonder why the input property in the OP is then also set by a service call...

Comment: @KurtHamilton why rename the local var on my ngFor loop?

Comment: I meant that the property name in the .ts file in the OP is `@Input() recipe: Recipe[]`. There is currently no `recipes` property. I have a feeling OP might get confused by this and blame you for your answer not working.

Comment: OP is also doing this for some reason: `<app-recipes *ngFor="let recipeEl of recipe"></app-recipes>`. The code is a bit confused.

Comment: @KurtHamilton that's true! If he create a stackblitz it will be cleaner for us too to help him

Comment: Yeah sorry as you can probably tell I am very new to Angular! I have removed the @Input as I discovered it wasn't needed. I also now know that the *ngFor should be placed in recipes.html rather that the root component which I have now updated. I will update the recipe to recipes as this obviously makes more sense.

Comment: Also, I haven't used Slackbitz before but I'm taking a look now!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Recipe is an array and you have iterate it, so :

```
<div *ngFor="let element of recipe" class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ element.name }}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ element.description }}</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Great answer but should that not be ngFor instead of ngIf

Comment: Obviously it is a typo, but thank you very much who was quick to put the vote, really compliments